# Getting an address and deleting slashes

Tags: php

I have a web address like this :

```
test.project-heberg.fr/admin/test.php
```

I want to put in a var only this part :

```
test.project-heberg.fr/
```

How can I do it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: why we do your homework? You have try something with your own if you stuck somewhere then have to come here to ask with your tried code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to know the hostname? so use the following code:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

or

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

All server vars are found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[explode](https://www.php.net/function.explode) will do the trick

```
 $string = "test.project-heberg.fr/admin/test.php" 
 $res= explode("/", $string);
 echo $res[0]."/"; // test.project-heberg.fr/
```

or using [strstr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
$res   = strstr($string, '/',true);
echo $res."/"; // test.project-heberg.fr/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it many ways. one of the suggested way is..

```
  $a= "test.project-heberg.fr/admin/test.php";
  $b = strstr($a, "/",TRUE)."/";
  echo $b;
```

Answer (score 0):

use::

```
$str = "test.project-heberg.fr/admin/test.php";
echo strstr($str, '/', true) . "/";
```